# jquery each splitting json to single characters

Tags: php, jquery, json, each

Here is my json object:

```
var home = "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"img\":\"assets\\\/1.jpg\",\"headline\":\"This is the headline in the pedu.\",\"text\":\"To the ipedu\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"img\":\"assets\\\/2.jpg\",\"headline\":\"This is the headline in the pedulence.\",\"text\":\"To the pendula\"}]";
```

When i try to loop through the object like this:

```
$.each(home, function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

I got each single character logged instead of the whole strings.

Example:
String {0: "["}
 localhost:317
String {0: "{"}
 localhost:317
String {0: """}
 localhost:317
String {0: "i"}
 localhost:317
String {0: "d"}
 localhost:317
String {0: """}
 localhost:317
String {0: ":"}
 localhost:317
String {0: """}
 localhost:317
String {0: "1"}
 localhost:317
String {0: """}
 localhost:317
String {0: ","}
 localhost:317
String {0: """}
 localhost:317
String {0: "i"}

What am i doing wrong? How to loop through the objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, what you have is not a JSON object; it's a string that contains an object representation according to the JSON specification.

To convert that string into the expected object you have to parse it first using `$.parseJSON()`.

**TL;DR**

Change this:

```
$.each(home, function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

To:

```
$.each($.parseJSON(home), function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because home is a string. I asssume you intended to declare it using object literal syntax (eg as an array):

```
var home = [{\"id\":\"1\",\"img\":\"assets\\\/1.jpg\",\"headline\":\"This is the headline in the pedu.\",\"text\":\"To the ipedu\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"img\":\"assets\\\/2.jpg\",\"headline\":\"This is the headline in the pedulence.\",\"text\":\"To the pendula\"}];
```